# Remove default white space around inline-block elemnts

Tags: html, css

If I have the following code:

```
<div class="inline"></div>
<div class="inline"></div>

.inline {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

You'll notice that there seems to be some default white space still around the `divs`. And the only way I can fix this is by doing this:

```
<div class="inline"></div><div class="inline"></div>
```

Which makes my markup look untidy. Can I fix this just in CSS?

Comment: @TeutaKoraqi float might mess up different things in the style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding a 0 font size in the div container. But you'll need to change the other font sizes inside the div individually:

**CSS**

```
.container {
    font-size: 0;
}

.inline {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    font-size: 10px;
    background: red;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="inline"></div>
    <div class="inline"></div>
</div>
```

**A working fiddle can be found [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/baL1zshb/1/)**.

Not a perfect solution. But this worked for me.
The other solution is that one you've provided above.

Comment: It's not working on my **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/baL1zshb/)**

Comment: @SyamPillai, because your Fiddle is wrong however the answer is correct.

Comment: @Anton, Yeah answer will be correct. But can you please check what's error in my fiddle

Comment: @SyamPillai, sorry, sometimes I write faster than I think. The answer is correct only partially. The idea presented in the answer is correct, the code is not (I will suggest an edit). Here is an updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/baL1zshb/1/) which works - container has to have `font-size: 0`, not the inline items.

Comment: @Anton thanks for the edit. I just noticed the bug. I am on the mobile site of SO, therefore I couldn't test it before. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Look at the very good article which comes with a few different approaches: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/ and choose the best fir for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by wrapping them inside a `flex-box`
Creating a parent for them and giving `display: flex` to the parent will work

```css
.inline {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
}
.container{
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inline"></div>
  <div class="inline"></div>
</div>
```